# Webpack configuration only for css and images

Tags: css, image, webpack

I'm building a CSS library with a specific Webpack configuration only to bundle CSS and images.

This is my current configuration:

```
  const CssEntryPlugin = require("css-entry-webpack-plugin");
  const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

  module.exports = {
      entry: {
          "styles": "./assets/css/lib.scss"
      },
      output: {
          path: __dirname + "/static/",
          filename: "lib.css"
      },
      module: {
          rules: [
              {
                  test: /\.scss$/,
                  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                      fallback: 'style-loader',
                      //resolve-url-loader may be chained before sass-loader if necessary
                      use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                  })
              },
              {
                  test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                  use: [
                      {
                          loader: 'file-loader',
                          options: {
                              loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                              options: {
                                  bypassOnDebug: true,
                              },
                          }
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ]
      },
      plugins: [
          new ExtractTextPlugin('lib.css'),
      ]
  };
```

The problem is that when I run it the images are not processed because they are not imported into the .css entry point file. How can I make sure that all the images are processed? Should I write a .js file to include both the CSS and the images as an entry point or there is a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to add some `require()` statements into you entry point .scss, or create a separate file, like you suggest. I've done the latter successfully.

Another other option is to provide a array as your entry point like this:

```
entry: {
  "styles": ["./assets/css/lib.scss", "./assets/img/whatever.png"]
},
```